# How does Mupirocin affect in staphylococcal infection?

Tags: microbiology

I found this sentence confusing

```
Transitor carriers of staphylococcal infections 70% because of mupirocin i/n.
```

Mupirocin is drug which affects some way.
I am not sure if the statement means inner neuronal.

I am little confused by the abbreviation **i/n**.
**What is the point of the sentence?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes from the usage of the Mupirocin: Its an antibiotic, which is used topically (on the skin, its not taken in form of pills). It binds specifically to the isoleucyl t-RNA synthetase in gram positive bacteria and Streptoccus and Staphylococcus and is used to fight intranasally (that what i/n stands for) infections with these bacteria. It inhibts the introduction of isoleucine into proteins. More informations can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mupirocin).